# Do you have any tips for C# Minification?

Tags: c#, xaml, minify

I need to minify some C# code in a handful of Silverlight .cs and .xmal files. What are your tips for maintaining one code base and running a "tool" to generate minified code for a project?

Are there any tools (like Resharper) that will do this? If not fully, partially or assist in some way...

EDIT: I realize that there is no need for C# minification. This is an exercise that I'm doing that does not make sense on the face of it. (This is not homework.)

Comment: Entering the MIX 10k coding challenge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a source-code obfuscator? They generally abbreviate names, etc - and certainly remove white space.

For example, [here](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/CSharpObfuscator.html), with demo [here](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/CSharpObfuscationExample.html) (although you'd probably want to disable the string encoding if possible). Note that this isn't a direct recommendation: this is just the first hit I got for [C# code obfuscator](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+code+obfuscator).

Comment: A rule based obfuscator would work - one where you could say "use no more than 2 characters per variable" etc.

Comment: Of course, if you have more variables than the "2 characters per variable" space can hold, you will have problems. (or methods, classes, etc...not just variables)

Answer (score 1):

Is that necessary? It was my understanding that the compiled .Net assembly would be sent across the wire, not the C# (or whatever language) source code.

Comment: This is probably a question relating to some assignment or contest.

Comment: Correct - only needed for this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two "Lessons Learned" posts from other 10k entrants:

[Thoughts on the MIX 10K challenge](https://web.archive.org/web/20110104170434/http://www.bluerosegames.com/SilverlightBrassTacks/post/Thoughts-on-the-MIX-10K-challenge.aspx)

[MIX09 10K Smart Coding Challenge](http://bragosphere.blogspot.com/2009/01/blog-post.html)