# C# Code Minification Tools and Techniques

Tags: c#, minify

I realize this is a rather odd request, but I was wondering if anyone was aware of some minification/obfuscation tools that work on C# source code (not a compiled assembly). I am trying to reduce the character count of an already written application to meet a character limit and I can't seem to find any tools that will help me achieve this task.

Main features I am interested in:

- Strip Whitespace
- Shorten Variable Names

It doesn't have to be a full on obfuscator, just something that will reduce the character count of a block of code quickly and conveniently.

**This is not intended to have any practical or real world application, it's for a competition.**

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: My I ask why your code has a character limit?

Comment: I'm trying to meet a chracter limit that's all. Nothing to do with security or anything.

Comment: but why is there a character limit, is it for a comp?

Comment: how long is the code it might be easier to do it by hand.

Comment: I think this is a pretty much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350705/do-you-have-any-tips-for-c-minification

Comment: I can absolutely do it by hand if need be, but I wanted to see if anyone was aware of such a tool before I went that route. I'm just investigating my options is all :)

Comment: Write your entire application in lambda expressions :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of any such tool, but it would not be too hard to do some variable renaming using the built in refactor tools in Visual Studio.

For the whitespace, a regex find-replace, to replace any multiple spaces (:Wh+ in VS replace) with a single space.

Comment: Merging multiple spaces to a single space might break the program if spaces are inside a string literal.

Answer (score 6):

I developed small lib for C# code minification [CSharpMinifier](https://github.com/KvanTTT/CSharpMinifier) based on [NRefactory](https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory). Now it can remove comments, whitespaces and line breaks. Next I'am planning to add identifier minification.

Answer (score 4):

@Ivan's CSharpMinifier didn't work for me. So I am using [this one](https://github.com/atifaziz/CSharpMinifier) instead. There is a [demo web app](https://atifaziz.github.io/CSharpMinifierDemo/) if you want to try.

Comment: This one is very good. Although it doesn't minify private member names, it does a good job of minifying the code (~50% for mine)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good online version to beautify/minify [Code Beautify](http://codebeautify.org/csharpviewer).